# Filtering on many-to-many association with Doctrine2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have an `Account` entity which has a collection of `Section` entities. Each `Section` entity has a collection of `Element` entities (OneToMany association). My problem is that instead of fetching all elements belonging to a section, I want to fetch all elements that belong to a section **and** are associated with a specific account. Below is my database model.

[image: Database model]

Thus, when I fetch an account, I want to be able to loop through its associated sections (this part is no problem), and for each section, I want to loop through its elements that are associated with the fetched account. Right now I have the following code.

```
$repository = $this->objectManager->getRepository('MyModule\Entity\Account');
$account = $repository->find(1);

foreach ($account->getSections() as $section) {
    foreach ($section->getElements() as $element) {
        echo $element->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it fetches all elements belonging to a given section, regardless of which account they are associated with. The generated SQL for fetching a section's elements is as follows.

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.section_id AS section_id3
FROM mydb.element t0
WHERE t0.section_id = ?
```

What I need it to do is something like the below (could be any other approach). It is important that the filtering is done with SQL.

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.section_id
FROM element AS e
INNER JOIN account_element AS ae ON (ae.element_id = e.id)
WHERE ae.account_id = ?
AND e.section_id = ?
```

I do know that I can write a method `getElementsBySection($accountId)` or similar in a custom repository and use DQL. If I can do that and somehow override the `getElements()` method on the `Section` entity, then that would be perfect. I would just very much prefer if there would be a way to do this through association mappings or at least by using existing getter methods. Ideally, when using an account object, I would like to be able to loop like in the code snippet above so that the "account constraint" is abstracted when using the object. That is, the user of the object does not need to call `getElementsByAccount()` or similar on a `Section` object, because it seems less intuitive.

I looked into the `Criteria` object, but as far as I remember, it cannot be used for filtering on associations.

So, what is the best way to accomplish this? Is it possible without "manually" assembling the `Section` entity with elements through the use of DQL queries? My current (and shortened) source code can be seen below. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Account
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyModule\Entity\Section")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="account_section",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="section_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $sections;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sections = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Getters and setters
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Section
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyModule\Entity\Element", mappedBy="section")
     */
    protected $elements;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->elements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Getters and setters
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Element
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var Section
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyModule\Entity\Section", inversedBy="elements")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="section_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $section;

    /**
     * @var \MyModule\Entity\Account
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyModule\Entity\Account")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="account_element",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="element_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $account;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to retrieve all `Element`s of all `Section`s of an `Account`, but only if those `Element`s are associated with that `Account`, and this from a getter in Account.

First off: An entity should never know of repositories. This breaks a design principle that helps you swap out the persistence layer. That's why you cannot simple access a repository from within an entity.

**Getters only**

If you only want to use getters in the entities, you can solve this by adding to following 2 methods:

```
class Section
{
    /**
     * @param  Account $accout
     * @return Element[]
     */
    public function getElementsByAccount(Account $accout)
    {
        $elements = array();

        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
            if ($element->getAccount() === $account) {
                $elements[] = $element->getAccount();
            }
        }

        return $elements;
    }
}

class Account
{
    /**
     * @return Element[]
     */
    public function getMyElements()
    {
        $elements = array()

        foreach ($this->getSections() as $section) {
            foreach ($section->getElementsByAccount($this) as $element) {
                $elements[] = $element;
            }
        }

        return $elements;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

The solution above is likely to perform several queries, the exact amount depending on how many `Section`s and `Element`s are associated to the `Account`.

You're likely to get a performance boost when you do use a Repository method, so you can optimize the query/queries used to retrieve what you want.

An example:

```
class ElementRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param  Account $account [description]
     * @return Element[]
     */
    public function findElementsByAccount(Account $account)
    {
        $dql = <<< 'EOQ'
SELECT e FROM Element e
JOIN e.section s
JOIN s.accounts a
WHERE e.account = ?1 AND a.id = ?2
EOQ;

        $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        $q->setParameters(array(
            1 => $account->getId(),
            2 => $account->getId()
        ));

        return $q->getResult();
    }
}
```

PS: For this query to work, you'll need to define the ManyToMany association between `Section` and `Account` as a bidirectional one.

**Proxy method**

A hybrid solution would be to add a proxy method to `Account`, that forwards the call to the repository you pass to it.

```
class Account
{
    /**
     * @param  ElementRepository $repository
     * @return Element[]
     */
    public function getMyElements(ElementRepository $repository)
    {
        return $repository->findElementsByAccount($this);
    }
}
```

This way the entity still doesn't know of repositories, but you allow one to be passed to it.

When implementing this, don't have `ElementRepository` extend `EntityRepository`, but [inject](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) the `EntityRepository` upon creation. This way you can still swap out the persistence layer without altering your entities.

Comment: The first solution should work, but does not seem so appealing because the filtering is done in memory and in SQL if I understand correctly. With the repository approach, I would be "assembling" the `Section` objects manually, right? That is, setting the elements myself instead of them being fetched automatically via an association. Perhaps [something like this](http://pastebin.com/CWAadsbB)? In that case, I might as well remove the association on the entity to ensure that incorrect sections are not fetched by mistake if not having assembled the object before using it. Good points, by the way!

Comment: With the first solution the db will simply fetch entities based on the defined associations. The filtering on a specific `Account` will be done in PHP only. That's why I suggest you do use a repository, because you can let the db fetch only those `Element`s you actually want (so the db does the filtering).

Comment: Okay, then we are on the same page. That's the solution I was considering to go for, but I just wanted to test the waters and see if the getter-approach was possible purely through SQL. Thank you for a great answer! :-)